# How to clean the json output of a @property variable in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The issues is, when I do a get request for this model, the JSON response is not clean making it difficult to work with in Retrofit.

Here is an example JSON output:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "restName": "Buddy's",
        "banner": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/buddysImg.jpg",
        "zipcode": 48212,
        "restRating": {
            "rating__avg": 4.0
        },
        "website": "Buddys.com",
        "phone": 3138929001,
        "restPrice": 0.0
    }
]
```

And this is how I'd like it to look:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "restName": "Buddy's",
        "banner": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/buddysImg.jpg",
        "zipcode": 48212,
        "restRating": 4.0,
        "website": "Buddys.com",
        "phone": 3138929001,
        "restPrice": 0.0
    }
]
```

Here is my model :

```
class Rest(models.Model):
    restName = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, default = " ")
    zipcode = models.PositiveIntegerField( null=False, default = 0)
    #restRating = models.FloatField( null=False, default = 0)
    banner = models.ImageField( null=True) 
    website = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, default = " ")
    phone = models.PositiveIntegerField( null=False, default = 0)
    restPrice = models.FloatField( null=False, default = 0)

    @property
    def restRating(self):
        avg = Rating.objects.filter(restId=self.pk).aggregate(Avg('rating'))
        return avg

    def __str__(self):
        return self.restName
```

And here is my serializer :

```
class restSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    restRating = serializers.FloatField

    class Meta:
        model = Rest
        fields = ['id', 'restName', 'banner', 'zipcode', 'restRating', 'website', 'phone', 'restPrice']
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can return only the value from your property. You need to change your property to this:

```
@property
def restRating(self):
    avg = Rating.objects.filter(restId=self.pk).aggregate(Avg('rating'))['rating__avg']
    return avg
```

from the [aggregate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset) docs:

> aggregate() is a terminal clause for a QuerySet that, when invoked,
>   returns a dictionary of name-value pairs. The name is an identifier
>   for the aggregate value; the value is the computed aggregate. The name
>   is automatically generated from the name of the field and the
>   aggregate function.